# ¿Existe manera de ponerle un título a mi data frame con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Me gustaría que a la hora de imprimir un data frame en la libreta, apareciera un título para dicho data frame. ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego [edit] la pregunta con el código que ha intentado, descripción completa de errores, resultados esperados, etcétera.

Answer (score 1):

No hay forma de añadir un título a un DataFrame, pero sí puedes añadir HTML a la salida de una celda, por lo que puedes usar esto para poner un título al *output*.

Aquí tienes una prueba de concepto:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)))

from IPython.display import HTML, display_html, display
display(HTML('<h2>Mi tabla</h2>'))
display_html(df)
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

### Actualización

Sí hay forma de ponerle una *caption*, pero eso elimina el resto del estilo por defecto que tenía la tabla originalmente, al menos así es en Google Collaboratory. Por ejemplo:

```
df.style.set_caption('Mi Tabla')
```

Produce:

[image: Resultado]

Si lo comparas con lo que salia antes, verás que ahora ya no aparecen sombradas las filas pares, ni usan el mismo número de dígitos cada celda, y el estilo de las cabeceras de columna es diferente, en mi opinión todo es más feo.

Con un poco de esfuerzo y definiendo estilos CSS apropiados la cosa puede mejorar bastante (observa que he definido estilos para la *caption* y para la tabla en general, intentando imitar los estilos por defecto de Collaboratory, incluyendo el fondo azul al pasar el ratón sobre la celda, además de fijar la precisión de salida a seis decimales):

```
display(HTML("""
<style>
  caption {font-weight: bold; font-size: 120%; }
  tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFF}
  tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #EEE}
  table {border-collapse: collapse;}
  td {padding: 0.5em; text-align:right;}
  thead > tr > th {text-align: right; padding: 0.5em;  background: #fff; border-bottom: solid 1pt #bbb;}
  tr:hover { background: #def;}
</style>"""))

display(df.style.set_caption('Mi Tabla').format("{:.6f}"))
```

El resultado es ahora:

[image: Resultado]